# Change slicer item based on a cell value for OLAP Cube

Tags: excel, vba, olap-cube, slicers

One of my EXCEL dashboard is connected with OLAP cube, I wanted to change a slicer from a cell value but due to shortage of visual basic expertise, I can't make it possible. Any help is highly appreciated. I can change slicer statistically like below but I need a dynamic changing of slicer.

```
If Sheets("Reports").Range("A2") = "2019/20" Then
'ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Fin_Year").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[02 All Dates].[Fin Year].[03 Fin Year].&[2019/20]")
End if
```

Note. My sheet name = Report

Cell value in A2 = 2019/20

Need to change slicer when cell value is change accordingly

Thank you
Nayeem :)

Comment: Are you just looking to dynamically change the `2019/20` in `Array("[02 All Dates].[Fin Year].[03 Fin Year].&[2019/20]")`? You can concatenate it in.

Comment: Yes, Ben you are absolutely right.. :-) is it possible to provide me some code please ?

Comment: Try: ...`Array("[02 All Dates].[Fin Year].[03 Fin Year].&[" & Sheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "]")`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of closing this question out (answered in comments):

All you need to do is concatenate the value in with `&`.

```
... = Array("[02 All Dates].[Fin Year].[03 Fin Year].&[" & Sheets("Reports").Range("A2").Value & "]")
```

Comment: How would I pass an array of items to the VisibleSlicerItemsList?  Would like to select a range of cells and use all those values to filter the slicer.  I have a simple bit of code to populate the array with the selected cells, but I get an error when trying to pass the array into the VisibleSlicerItemList:  ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Branch_Name").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array("[Dim Location].[Branch Name].&[sel_Array]")   It works if I just use the value from a specific cell, like the example your provided.

Comment: @Sean - sounds like you need to ask a new question!